# Test if elements of one array are included in another

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following arrays:

```
passing_grades = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
student2434 = ["F", "A", "C", "C", "B"]
```

and I need to verify that all elements in the `student` array are included in the `passing_grades` array. In the scenario above, `student2434` would return false. But this student:

```
student777 = ["C", "A", "C", "C", "B"]
```

would return `true`. I tried something like:

```
if student777.include? passing_grades then return true else return false end
```

without success. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
PASSING_GRADES = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

def passed?(grades)
  (grades - PASSING_GRADES).empty?
end
```

similar to what CDub had but without bug. more readable in my opinion

Comment: Kinda liking this one. Let me do some testing and see if it does what I need it to.

Answer (score 7):

You could have a method that does the difference of the arrays, and if any results are present, they didn't pass:

```
PASSING_GRADES = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

def passed?(grades)
  grades.all? {|grade| PASSING_GRADES.include?(grade)}
end
```

Example:

```
1.9.3-p484 :117 > student777 = ["C", "A", "C", "C", "B"]
 => ["C", "A", "C", "C", "B"] 
1.9.3-p484 :118 > passed?(student777)
 => true
1.9.3-p484 :118 > passed?(student2434)
 => false
```

Comment: Would `passing_grades - grades` return any passing grades the student didn't get? E.g. if the student only got Cs, would this return false because the difference includes As, Bs, and Ds?

Comment: His code simply removes all objects present in `grades` from the `PASSING_GRADES` array. This includes duplicates by the way, so `[1,1,2,1] - [1]` yields `[2]`.

Comment: @Michelle is correct - my answer has been modified.

Comment: Gave you an upvote CDub. Good code,but luri's is a little more succinct.